# JediScript - May the 4th be with you

Tags: python, interpreter, language-design

In honor of Star Wars day, I've put together this small Python program I'm calling JediScript. JediScript is essentially a scrapped-down version of BrainFuck without input or looping. Here are the commands in JediScript.

- `SlashWithSaber`: Move forward on the tape.
- `ParryBladeWithSaber`: Move backward on the tape.
- `StabWithSaber`: Increment a cell.
- `BlockBladeWithSaber`: Decrement cell.
- `UseForceWithHands`: Output the current cell.

Each command is semicolon `;` separated, like so: `StabWithSaber;UseForceWithHands`. Here's an example input. This will output the character `p`.

> ```
> StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;StabWithSaber;UseForceWithHands;
> ```

This is something that I threw together in about 20 minutes, so it's not the greatest, but I'd still appreciate a review.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
JediScript, BrainFuck for Star Wars.
May the 4th be with you.
"""


DEFAULT_SPLIT = ";"


"""
Variables below this are environment
variables for the user to modify.
"""
data_tape = [0 for _ in range(256)]
tape_pos  = 0


def increment_cell():
    global data_tape
    global tape_pos
    data_tape[tape_pos] += 1 if data_tape[tape_pos] <= 127 else 0


def decrement_cell():
    global data_tape
    global tape_pos
    data_tape[tape_pos] -= 1 if data_tape[tape_pos] >= 0 else 0


def move_forward():
    global tape_pos
    tape_pos += 1 if tape_pos <= len(data_tape) - 1 else 0


def move_backward():
    global tape_pos
    tape_pos -= 1 if tape_pos >= 0 else 0


def output_cell():
    print chr(data_tape[tape_pos])


"""
Dictionary contains tokens that reference
their relevant functions.
"""
TOKENS = {
    "SlashWithSaber": move_forward,
    "ParryBladeWithSaber": move_backward,
    "StabWithSaber": increment_cell,
    "BlockBladeWithSaber": decrement_cell,
    "UseForceWithHands": output_cell,
}


def execute_commands(tokenized_string):
    """
    Executes commands from the tokenized string.
    tokenized_string - The tokenized string
    """
    for token in tokenized_string:
        if token in TOKENS:
            TOKENS[token]()


def tokenize_input(string):
    """
    Tokenize a string into it's the form [ token, ... ]
    string - The string to tokenize.
    """
    string = string.replace(" ", "")
    string = string.split(DEFAULT_SPLIT)
    return string


def get_user_input(prompt):
    """
    Get input from the user.
    prompt - The prompt to be used.
    """
    while True:
        string = raw_input(prompt)
        string = tokenize_input(string)
        execute_commands(string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_user_input("JediScript $ ")
```

Comment: About your language: I guess new-line separated is easier to read.

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something, but what does the `spherical` notes do? Other than error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Why do you allow each cell of the tape to hold numbers from -1 to 128? seems like an odd range.
- in `move_backward()` why do you allow the tape to reach position -1?
- in `move_forward()` why do you allow the tape's position to be beyond the end of the tape?
- In general you should be using exclusive comparisons (without the =) as you'll make fewer mistakes.

Comment: I don't understand why using exclusive comparisons would make fewer mistakes ?

Comment: I don't either, but there's actually research on it. Coders who use an exclusive comparison for the top-end of the loop or the range make fewer off-by-one errors than coders who use the "-or-equal-to" comparators.

Comment: I would be interested in the link to that research!

Comment: Searched a while and all I came up with was https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html I'll keep looking